# Counting occurences in TeXnicCenter’s search and replace

Tags: texniccenter

Using TeXnicCenter 2.0 alpha 4 to run MiKTeX 2.9.

When performing a Replace *specimen1* with *specimen2* under Seach\Replace, the output used to show how many occurences had been found.

This was an excellent method of checking in some circumstances, but seems to have been dropped and I cannot find a way to retrieve it.

Is there any way of recovering this option?

Comment: I don’t see any. You should search for a report of this issue as bug or feature request on [TeXnicCenter Bug Tracker](http://www.texniccenter.org/component/weblinks/32-links-contribute/23-issues) and if not add yourself one.